# Can't use date and time picker library

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting a gradle error when trying to add a dependency. I'm trying to use Wdullaer's library, but getting an error message:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.0.1] /home/jonathon/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/materialdatetimepicker-4.0.1.aar/e6a687a3cda7a3733aea1e4617c99341/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

I've tried to change the minSdkVerison, but still getting some kind of error.

Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.0.1'
```

}

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker

If it's impossible to use for any reason, does anyone have any suggestions for a date and time picker library or some kind? Thanks.

Comment: When you say "I've tried to change the minSdkVerison, but still getting some kind of error.", what is that new error?

Answer (score 0):

use this date picker method for better performance.. its also suppored in min device.hope it will be useful to you.

```
  private void datePicker(){

    // Get Current Date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   final int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   final int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
   final int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


    //get day Name
            SimpleDateFormat sdfday = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            Date d_name = new Date(mYear-1900,mMonth,mDay);
            final String dayOfTheWeek = sdfday.format(d_name);

    final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,R.style.picker1,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {



                    //get calendar format
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
                    final String formatedDate = sdf.format(new Date(year-1900, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth));

                    date_time = formatedDate;

                    //*************Call Time Picker Here ********************

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
    datePickerDialog.show();
}



   private void timePicker(){
    // Get Current Time
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    // Launch Time Picker Dialog
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,R.style.picker1,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {



                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) {


                    DateInput.setText(date_time+" "+String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));

                    Log.d("datenew",date_time + hourOfDay+":"+minute);
                }
            }, mHour, mMinute, false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```